# Is it okay to use functions as object proprty name?

Tags: javascript, function

Here is code sample:

```
var eventStack = {};
function addEvent (fn) {
  eventStack[fn] = fn;
}
function removeEvent (fn) {
  delete eventStack[fn];
}
addEvent(alert);
addEvent(console.log);
addEvent(addEvent);
```

it works whatever function I define myself, but doesn't work for console.log. Instead it's replaced with _firebugignore.

I think there is some magic with toString property

**EDIT** hmng, I just run my code again, and It worked fine for console.log, previous time both key and value were replaced buy "_firebuignore", I suppose its higgs bugson

Comment: In Chrome when I do `alert( eventStack[ console.log ] );` I get the expected `function log() { [native code] }`. Nothing wrong there.

Comment: What exactly does not work for console.log, `removeEvent`? And yes, `toString` applied on builtin functions like `console.log` is implementation-dependent. What did you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would solve a problem you're having, although I'm not sure if you actually have a problem, but why not use the function name as the key (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) and then the value can be the reference to the function.

Comment: @ianpgall: It would likely cause more problems, because most functions today are <s>declared</s>expressed *anonymous* - their name is the empty string, and they would overwrite each other.

Comment: @Bergi True, I hadn't considered anonymous functions. Would it work with normal function declarations though?

Comment: @ianpgall Maybe, but not with `console.log` either…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is some magic with [`Function.prototype.toString`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.2): It's implementation-dependent, it only needs to return a representation of the function which is [*FunctionDeclaration*](http://es5.github.com/#x13)-syntax-like. And of course it can't return a JS function for all those environment-builtin functions (like `console.log`).

However, I don't think it is a good idea to identify a function by its string representation at all. It can easily happen that two different functions end up in the same string (examples: two identical function expressions, identical function declarations in different scopes - or closures, builtin-functions (`Array.prototype.toString.toString() == Function.prototype.toString.toString()`).

Instead, use an Array for your `eventStack` and check for a function's existance by `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Property names can only be strings.  Other types are coerced to string values as necessary. When you iterate over properties with `for ... in` you get strings.